# Removing power cord retainer from floor lamp

Tags: floor, lamp

I bought a Nickle floor lamp years ago from lowes. And its been working fine but just recently it stopped lighting up. I checked the bulb and its not that. I have not been able to progress any further on fixing it because of some kind of power cord retainer stuck in the pole itself.
[image]
Here is a picture of what it looks like.

Any suggestions of how to proceed?

Comment: It looks like the metal is bent in on two sides to hold the white cord retainer. And the cord retain has flat spots.  Perhaps you just need to rotate it to line them up.

Answer (score 2):

First unplug the lamp.

Undo the bulb and test the plug end and the bulb socket to check the wire is not broken/makes contact all the way.

Usually the problem is at the switch and/or loose wire on bulb socket.

The centre post might be push down to much also. Carefully pulling the centre post up a bit might fix it.

If the wire is broken, then it should just need a small screwdriver or similar to pop that cable holder out.